# Non-breaking spaces and punctuation on Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, typography, input-methods

Not exactly ultra-high priority, but given that in French you're *supposed* to put non-breaking spaces before some punctuation (: ; ? !), what are we going to do about it?

- Type them in manually?
- Ask the devs for 'something' (like Ctrl-Shift-Space in Word)?

*(Sandbox: just checking to see if nbsp's get eaten)*

**Afterthought** What about 'French quotes' (« ») too?

**Related question on main meta:**

- [Please don't escape & in a comment if it's part of an &nbsp;](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104370/please-dont-escape-in-a-comment-if-its-part-of-an-nbsp)
- [Please preserve spaces before punctuation in title. At least unbreakable ones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103855/please-preserve-spaces-before-punctuation-in-title-at-least-unbreakable-ones)

**UPDATE** I've rolled a [user-script](https://stackapps.com/questions/2569/convert-ctrl-space-to-non-break-space-for-flu) to convert Ctrl-spaces to non-break-spaces, and it now also converts `"` to `«` or `»` (alternately).

Comment: I guess a greasemonkey script could help. Not sure how to hook into the key-handlers in the markdown editor though...

Comment: I hate that about French. This is the one rule I deliberately never follow, because I think it's stupid and ugly.

Comment: Related question on main [Is there an explanation for why there is a space before certain punctuation marks?](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/46/is-there-an-explanation-for-why-there-is-a-space-before-certain-punctuation-marks/107#107)

Comment: @Borror0, [apparently](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=135374&page=3) in Quebec they don't do it so much...

Comment: See also http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/a/237/82

Answer (score 8):

It might be very useful if the devs could add a button to the WYSIWYG bar in the editor to typeset quotes (and maybe accents for some people on qwerty keyboards?).

Comment: Is there a way to get these quotes on a US Qwerty keyboard?  E.g. using the US-International keyboard setting you can get things like é á ç by typing ' + letter. Is there a similar way easy way to get the French quotes?

Comment: Never mind it is Right Alt + [ or ] to get « and ».  We might need a FAQ for this.

Comment: @Bryan, doesn't work on my UK keyboard :(

Comment: On my MacBook Pro, `right alt` + `backslash` gives `«` , and I can't find anything that gets me `»` (which I just copied and pasted from @Bryan's comment). (Really? I can't put a backslash in `this style`?!)

Comment: @Abby - try adding `shift` to make it `alt-shift-backslash`. (And the `alt` key is usually called `option`, I believe.) If that doesn't work, or to find other characters, launch the Keyboard Viewer and you should be able to find the right key combination (hit command, option,... to see the characters change)

Comment: @Joubarc - got it, thanks!

Comment: @Abby you're most welcome! (And I ate vegan chili with torillas for lunch)

Answer (score 4):

I think most people who care about it already know how to typeset no-break spaces (on my Mac, it's alt+space). I have the following order of decreasing preference:

1. correct use of no-break spaces around punctuation
2. use of regular spaces
3. English-style spacing (i.e., no space before a colon, for example)

Comment: I'm not sure that there's anything built-in in Windows for that...

Comment: @Benjol use a Mac then (OK, uase alt-0160)

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the 'French quotes', the question I just [asked here](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/115/is-it-necessary-to-use-guillemets-when-quoting-in-french-or-may-one-use-english) may be of relevance.  If it's OK to use doublequotes in general, their usage here should not be seen as 'incorrect'.

Comment: And we'd avoid having to use nbsp too, win all the way :)

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I use the [enhanced French keyboard driver](http://users.numericable.be/denis.liegeois/kbdfrac.htm) for Windows. With it, I can access missing symbols on French keyboard very easily. The most used (and the ones most relevant to this discussion) are:

- AltGr+Q --> «
- AltGr+S --> »
- AltGr+< --> non-breaking space (normal, not narrow)

Accented capitals, ligatures and much more are also accessible with this driver.

It works only on Windows, though. And only for people who already have a French keyboard.

Comment: [related and more complete](http://ytrezq.sdfeu.org/Outils/Xorg‐fr) *(supporte l’écriture correcte des abréviations)*. Les utilisateur de système d’exploitations basé sur Xorg. ne seront pas dépaysé par ce clavier. I also support exotic plateforms, and I’d be happy to support things like PowerPC with some help. For non Windows® users, the format of Xorg keyboard configurations files is fairly simple.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to use a non-breaking space instead of narrow non-breaking space.
Regarding [wikipedia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ponctuation#Les_espaces_autour_des_signes_de_ponctuation_.28r.C3.A8gles_actuelles.29), we could use narrow or simple non-breaking space.

[This page](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/120/alternatives-a-la-finale-e-tonique-dans-chante-je-juste) for example is ugly on Firefox 5 or Chrome 15 (Windows) [image: ugly narrow non-breaking spaces]
For information, it's well displayed on Firefox 3.0.4 or Firefox 4.0 (Fedora).

Comment: See [here](http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/questions/235/is-there-a-french-language-and-usage-character-map/237#237), we are collecting such kind of information.

Comment: For Firefox I suggest updating and https://bugzilla.mozilla.org

Comment: @Evpok the problem remains in windows title with Firefox 7.0, but it looks good for display.

Comment: @chepseska: Same on nightly. [Bug filed](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=691390).